# Why is there nothing in the body of the email upon submission of this form?

Tags: php, html

my PHP code:

```
$myemail = myemail;
$subject = "success";
if(isset($_POST['firstname'])){ $name = $_POST['firstname']; } 
if(isset($_POST['lastname'])){ $price = $_POST['lastname']; } 

$message = "$firstname $lastname";
mail($myemail, $subject, $message);
```

my html using twitter bootstrap:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" name="application" method="POST" action="submission.php">
<legend></legend>
<div class="control-group">
<label class="control-label" for="firstname">First Name</label>
<div class="controls">
<input type="text" id="firstname" name="firstname" placeholder="First Name">
</div>
</div>
<div class="control-group">
<label class="control-label" for="lastname">Last Name</label>
<div class="controls">
<input type="text" id="lastname" name="lastname" placeholder="Last Name">
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" id="submit">Submit</button>
</div>
</div>
</form>
```

I receive the email, but there is nothing in the body.

Comment: You're extracting the POST variables into `$name` and `$price` but putting `$firstname` and $`lastname` in the email.

Answer (score 1):

You're using the wrong variables. `$name` and `$price` in:

```
$name  = $_POST['firstname']; // should be $firstname
$price = $_POST['lastname']; // should be $lastname
```

& in conjunction with:

```
$message = "$firstname $lastname";
```

change it to:

```
$firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
$lastname  = $_POST['lastname'];
```

---

***Or,*** use `$message = "$name $price";` while leaving the rest of your code intact. Either way, variables need to match up and to remain consistent throughout the code's execution.

Use error reporting:

- **http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php**

which would have signaled an Undefined index error.

---

***Additional notes:***

Your code does not contain additional headers, especially a `From:` which stands to be rejected by many servers, or ending up in [**Spam**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_spam).

Use proper mail headers:

- **http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php**

as per documentation:

```
$to      = 'nobody@example.com';
$subject = 'the subject';
$message = 'hello';
$headers = 'From: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

Comment: <darth vader voice>All too easy</darth vader voice>

Comment: Luke, this is my friend John; don't zap him (too hard) @JohnConde

Answer (score 0):

> if(isset($_POST['firstname'])){ $name = $_POST['firstname']; } 
>   if(isset($_POST['lastname'])){ $price = $_POST['lastname']; }
>
> $message = "$firstname $lastname";

You must be kidding.
$name =...
$price =...
..."$firstname $lastname"
There are no values assigned to $firstname/$lastname variables, maybe use "$name $price" instead?